# Get more juice out of the processor in addition to multiprocessing for a python code

Tags: python, process, parallel-processing, scheduling

I am already doing multiprocessing but that's not enough. 
So, this may sound stupid and immature but is there a way I could get more time slot on the scheduler for my python code basically to get more runtime on my CPU ? I am doing some data analysis and this might help. I have paralleled the code using multiprocesses but even that's not enough and I am thinking since I have 4 cores increasing the no. of processes won't help me any way. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get more CPU time than your CPU can provide. Technically, you could hack your OS' scheduler, but if you're *that* good, you don't have these problems in the first place. To squeezes some percentage, disable all other running processes, that'll have the same effect. If you *really* want to be faster, Python is your problem.

If you're using python2, give [pypy](http://pypy.org) a try. It's an alternative interpreter doing JIT compilation, i.e. optimizing your code at runtime. If you're doing native python code, try the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) or [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) libraries. If that isn't enough, use [Cython](http://cython.org) or write your own C kernels.